# Criteria Query EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

how can I write criteria query for below PL/Sql code?

```
SELECT a.eqis_type, a.eqis_des, a.eqis_rate
  FROM eqis a
 WHERE a.eqis_date IN (SELECT MAX (b.eqis_date)
                         FROM eqis b
                        WHERE b.eqis_type = a.eqis_type)
ORDER BY eqis_type;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote it in native query. but I want to know how I write a query using criteria query like this ---------->>

Comment: CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
  Root<Lsbr> lsbr = cq.from(Lsbr.class);

  cq.multiselect(lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrCode), lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrDes), lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrAdd1), lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrAdd2),
    lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrAdd3), lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrAdd4), lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrType1), lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrType2),
    lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrDist), lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrZone)).orderBy(cb.asc(lsbr.get(Lsbr_.lsbrCode)));

  return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

Comment: edit your question and put the Criteria there, not on the comments :)